# Adding Sub Children to RDF using Jena

Tags: java, xml, rdf, sparql, jena

Okay I've got a problem I'd appreciate someone spreading some light on. Basically I have the following example below

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://test.com">
<hasX></hasX>
<hasY></hasY>
<hasA></hasA>
<hasA></hasA>
<hasA></hasA>
</rdf:Description>
```

I'm trying to produce the following:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://test.com">
<hasX></hasX>
<hasY></hasY>
<hasZ>
<hasA></hasA>
<hasA></hasA>
<hasA></hasA>
</hasZ>
</rdf:Description>
```

I've tried adding Property to a Property then a Resource, declaring new Resource, adding Literals, every possible combination of these, however the close I've gotten is it to generate a new rdf:description block containing the data I want, outside of the original rdf:description making it worthless.

I really don't want another `<rdf:Description rdf:about="">` to describe the `A` tags.

Here's a small test example

```
String NS = "http://example.com/test";      
Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
Resource r = m.createResource("http://meetup/nyc");

Property p = m.createProperty(XmlParser.NS + "hasData");
Property p2 = m.createProperty(XmlParser.NS + "hasData");
Property p3 = m.createProperty(XmlParser.NS + "hasData");

r.addProperty(p, "somedata");
r.addProperty(p2, "somedata2");
r.addProperty(p3, "somedata3");

m.write(System.out);
```

Comment: You got your answer from MikeJ. By the way, I suggest you start thinking in terms of RDF triples and don't try to look/learn RDF from its RDF/XML serialization. Use Turtle or N-Triples instead. Think graphs, not trees.

Comment: castagna makes a very good point. When I started looking at RDF I used RDF/XML and it was difficult not to retain a mental model of XML and trees rather than triples and graphs. Switching to Turtle would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a `Resource` from a model doesn't automatically add it to that model. I generally add triples to a model via one of the `add` methods of the Model class:

```
    String NS = "http://example.com/test#";
    Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    Resource r = m.createResource("http://meetup/nyc");

    Property p = m.createProperty(NS + "hasData");

    m.add(r, p, "somedata");
    m.add(r, p, "more data");

    m.write(System.out);
```

This will create:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
           xmlns:j.0="http://example.com/test#" > 
     <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://meetup/nyc">
         <j.0:hasData>more data</j.0:hasData>
         <j.0:hasData>somedata</j.0:hasData>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, however I'm still unsure if it's possible to write a model that outputs my example above, that's my goal. Just to note I already have a complete working model of my data, I just want to add a sub child to a child as shown in the example, thanks again

Comment: `m.add(m.createStatement(s,p,o))` can be abbreviated to `m.add(s,p,o)`

Comment: Ash - I don't think you can get the structure you need without additional URIs or bnodes. RDF using subject, predicate, object, but you want to drop the subject aspect in the hasZ to hasA tree that you give in your example.

Answer (score 2):

As the other responders have said, don't think in terms of the XML tree structure. However, if seeing your graph in an XML tree is helpful to your understanding of the model, change the output syntax to the compact RDF/XML form:

```
m.write( System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV" );
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I completely understand what you guys are saying and I really do appreciate your input. Basically this sadly boils down to a requirement which is out of context and not neccessary. As a last resort I may parse the rdf manually and insert the tags using a little regex. Horrible but it seems this is not possible.

Comment: Just realised that this will invalidate the rdf document, I'll leave it out.